# Jmeter regular extractor

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract the value icToken i.e.,[1Og0OGBDLBVDZgO2] in the following url
https://inw00007322:8443/processdesigner?icToken=1Og0OGBDLBVDZgO2&validateTokenUrl=http://INVRLX61CEP100:16006/saas/api/v2/user/validateToken.

Any Help would be appreciated. Please also specify which option to select in jmeter example-> response header ,url, body etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Regular Expression Extractor.

Reference Name: Any you like

Regular Expression: `icToken=(.*?)&validateTokenUrl`

Template: $1$

Match No: 1

If this is response URL, check Main sample - URL. If this URL is contained in response data, check body.